# Is Python requests doing something wrong here, or is my POST request lacking something?

Tags: python, post, http-post, tumblr, python-requests

I'm currently writing a program which will help users to determine optimal times to make a post on tumblr. As with Twitter, most followers have so many subscriptions that there is no way they can keep up, meaning it's best to know when one's own specific following is (mostly) online. On tumblr this can be determined in two ways -- first whether they have recently shared any content which was recently posted, and secondly whether they have recently added to their liked-posts list.

Frustratingly, even when set to 'public', the liked-posts stream of an arbitrary user  (other than self) is only available to logged-in entities. As far as I know, that means I've either got to upload a login-cookie to the application every so often, or get this post-request working.

I've looked at a number of successful outbound requests via Opera's inspector but I must still be missing something, or perhaps **requests** is doing something that the server is rejecting no matter what I do.

The essence of the problem is below. This is currently written in Python 2.7
and uses [Python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). To run it yourself, update the e and p pair at the top of get_login_response() to a real set of values.

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Login:

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.session()

    def get_hidden_fields(self):
        """ -> string. tumblr dynamically generates a key for its login forms
        This should extract that key from the form so that the POST-data to
        login will be accepted.
        """
        pageRequest = requests.Request("GET","https://www.tumblr.com/login")
        received = self.session.send( pageRequest.prepare() )
        html = BeautifulSoup(received.content)
        hiddenFieldDict = {}
        hiddenFields = html.find_all("input",type="hidden")
        for x in hiddenFields: hiddenFieldDict[x["name"]]=x["value"]
        return hiddenFieldDict

    def get_login_response(self):
        e = u"dead@live.com"
        p = u"password"
        endpoint = u"https://tumblr.com/login"
        payload = { u"user[email]": e,
                    u"user[password]": p,
                    u"user[age]":u"",
                    u"tumblelog[name]": u"",
                    u"host": u"www.tumblr.com",
                    u"Connection:":u"keep-alive",
                    u"Context":u"login",
                    u"recaptcha_response_field":u""
                  }
        payload.update( self.get_hidden_fields() )
    ##        headers = {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"}
        headers = {u"Content-Type":u"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                   u"Connection:":u"keep-alive",
                   u"Origin":u"https://tumblr.com",
                   u"Referer": u"https://www.tumblr.com/login",
                   u"User-Agent":u"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36 OPR/18.0.1284.68",
                   u"Accept":u"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
                   u"Accept-Encoding":u"gzip,deflate,sdch",
                   u"Accept-Language":u"en-US,en;q=0.8",
                   u"Cache-Control":u"max-age=0"
                   #"Content-Length":VALUE is still needed
                   }
        # this cookie is stale but it seems we these for free anyways,
        #  so I'm not sure whether it's actually needed. It's mostly
        #  google analytics info.
        sendCookie = {"tmgioct":"52c720e28536530580783210",
                      "__qca":"P0-1402443420-1388781796773",
                      "pfs":"POIPdNt2p1qmlMGRbZH5JXo5k",
                      "last_toast":"1388783309",
                      "capture":"GDTLiEN5hEbMxPzys1ye1Gf4MVM",
                      "logged_in":"0",
                      "_ga":"GA1.2.2064992906.1388781797",
                      "devicePixelRatio":"1",
                      "documentWidth":"1280",
                      "anon_id":"VNHOJWQXGTQXHNCFKYJQUMUIVQBRISPR",
                      "__utma":"189990958.2064992906.1388781797.1388781797.1388781797.1",
                      "__utmb":"189990958.28.10.1388781797",
                      "__utmc":"189990958",
                      "__utmz":"189990958.1388781797.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)"}
        loginRequest = requests.Request("POST",
                                        endpoint,
                                        headers,
                                        data=payload,
                                        cookies=sendCookie # needed?
##                                        ,auth=(e,p) # may not be needed
                                        )

        contentLength = len(loginRequest.prepare().body)
        loginRequest.data.update({u"Content-Length":unicode(contentLength)})
        return self.session.send( loginRequest.prepare() )

l = Login()
res = l.get_login_response()
print "All cookies: ({})".format(len(l.session.cookies))
print l.session.cookies # has a single generic cookie from the initial GET query
print "Celebrate if non-empty:"
print res.cookies # this should theoretically contain the login cookie
```

Output on my end:

```
All cookies: (1)
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie tmgioct=52c773ed65cfa30622446430 for www.tumblr.com/>]>
Celebrate if non-empty:
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>
```

Bonus points if my code is insecure and you have pointers for me on that in addition . I chose **requests** module for its simplicity, but if it lacks features and my goal is possible using **httplib2** or something I am willing to switch.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of things you're not doing that you need to be, and quite a few things you *are* doing that you don't.

Firstly, go back and examing the POST fields being sent on your login request. When I do this in Chrome, I see the following:

```
user[email]:<redacted>
user[password]:<redacted>
tumblelog[name]:
user[age]:
recaptcha_public_key:6Lf4osISAAAAAJHn-CxSkM9YFNbirusAOEmxqMlZ
recaptcha_response_field:
context:other
version:STANDARD
follow:
http_referer:http://www.tumblr.com/logout
form_key:!1231388831237|jS7l2SHeUMogRjxRiCbaJNVduXU
seen_suggestion:0
used_suggestion:0
```

Your Requests-based POST is missing a few of these fields, specifically `recaptcha_public_key`, `version`, `follow`, `http_referer`, `form_key`, `seen_suggestion` and `used_suggestion`.

These fields are not optional: they will need to be sent on this POST. Some of these can safely be used generically, but the *safest* way to get these is to get the data for the login page itself, and use BeautifulSoup to pull the values out of the HTML. I'm going to assume you've got the skillset to do that (e.g. you know how to find form inputs in HTML and parse them to get their default values).

A good habit to get in here is to start using a tool like Wireshark or tcpdump to examine your requests HTTP traffic, and compare it to what you get from Chrome/Opera. This will allow you to see what is and isn't being sent, and how the two requests differ.

Secondly, once you start hitting the login page you won't need to send cookies on your POST, so you can stop doing that. More generally, when using a requests `Session` object, you shouldn't input any additional cookies: just emulate the flow of HTTP requests from an actual browser and your cookies state will be fine.

Thirdly, you're massively over-specifying your headers dictionary. Most of the fields you're providing will be automatically populated by Requests. Now, given that you're trying to emulate a browser (Opera by the looks of things), you will want to override a few of them, but most can be left alone. You should be using this header dictionary:

```
{
    u"Origin":u"https://tumblr.com",
    u"Referer": u"https://www.tumblr.com/login",
    u"User-Agent":u"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36 OPR/18.0.1284.68",
    u"Accept":u"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    u"Accept-Language":u"en-US,en;q=0.8",
}
```

Below is a list of the fields I removed from your header dictionary and why I removed them:

- **Content-Type**: When you provide a dictionary to the `data` argument in Requests, we set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for you. There's no need to do it yourself.
- **Connection**: Requests manages HTTP connection pooling and keep-alives itself: don't get involved in the process, it'll just go wrong.
- **Accept-Encoding**: Again, please let Requests set this unless you're actually prepared to deal with decoding the content. Requests only knows how to do `gzip` and `deflate`: if you send `sdch` and actually get it back, you'll have to decode it yourself. Best not to advertise you support it.
- **Cache-Control**: POST requests cannot be cached, so this is irrelevant.

Fourth, and I want to be very clear here, **do not calculate Content-Length yourself**. Requests will do it for you and will get it right. If you send that header yourself, all kinds of weird bugs can come up that the Requests core dev team have to chase. There is never a good reason to set that header yourself. With this in mind, you can stop using `PreparedRequest` objects and just go back to using `session.post()`.